# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

How can I solve the error presented?

this is my service :

```
@Service
public class EmisionPesoService {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private final String URL = "https://desa-dapinstituciones.bancoestado.cl/api-gtw-emision-pesos/dap-min-pub/emision-pesos";

    public EmisionPesosDto postEmisionPesos(EmisionPesosBody emisionPesosBody, String accessToken) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);


        HttpEntity<EmisionPesosBody> entity = new HttpEntity<>(emisionPesosBody, headers);

        ResponseEntity<EmisionPesosDto> response = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.POST, entity, EmisionPesosDto.class);

        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

this is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class EmisionPesoController {

    @Autowired
    private EmisionPesoService emisionPesoService;


    @PostMapping(value = "/emision-pesos", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public EmisionPesosDto emisionPesos(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String accessToken,
                                        @RequestBody Integer CodigoMoneda,
                                        @RequestBody Integer Plazo,
                                        @RequestBody BigDecimal MontoDeposito,
                                        @RequestBody String IndicadorRenovacion,
                                        @RequestBody Integer RutCliente,
                                        @RequestBody String DigitoRutCliente,
                                        @RequestBody Long NumCuentaCorriente,
                                        @RequestBody String RUC,
                                        @RequestBody String RUE,
                                        @RequestBody String FiscaliaRegional,
                                        @RequestBody String FiscaliaZonal,
                                        @RequestBody Integer RutUsuarioEmisor,
                                        @RequestBody String DigitoRutUsuarioEmisor) {
        EmisionPesosBody emisionPesosBody = new EmisionPesosBody();
        emisionPesosBody.setCodigoMoneda(CodigoMoneda);
        emisionPesosBody.setPlazo(Plazo);
        emisionPesosBody.setMontoDeposito(MontoDeposito);
        emisionPesosBody.setIndicadorRenovacion(IndicadorRenovacion);
        emisionPesosBody.setRutCliente(RutCliente);
        emisionPesosBody.setDigitoRutCliente(DigitoRutCliente);
        emisionPesosBody.setNumCuentaCorriente(NumCuentaCorriente);
        emisionPesosBody.setRUC(RUC);
        emisionPesosBody.setRUE(RUE);
        emisionPesosBody.setFiscaliaRegional(FiscaliaRegional);
        emisionPesosBody.setFiscaliaZonal(FiscaliaZonal);
        emisionPesosBody.setRutUsuarioEmisor(RutUsuarioEmisor);
        emisionPesosBody.setDigitoRutUsuarioEmisor(DigitoRutUsuarioEmisor);

        return emisionPesoService.postEmisionPesos(emisionPesosBody , accessToken);

    }
}
```

And the corresponding data

```
@Data
public class EmisionPesosBody {

    private Integer CodigoMoneda;
    private Integer Plazo;
    private BigDecimal MontoDeposito;
    private String IndicadorRenovacion;
    private Integer RutCliente;
    private String DigitoRutCliente;
    private Long NumCuentaCorriente;
    private String RUC;
    private String RUE;
    private String FiscaliaRegional;
    private String FiscaliaZonal;
    private Integer RutUsuarioEmisor;
    private String DigitoRutUsuarioEmisor;
}

@Data
public class EmisionPesosDto {


    private int code;
    private String message;
    private EmisionPesosPayloadDto payload;
}

@Data
public class EmisionPesosPayloadDto  {

    private String CodProducto;
    private String NumOperacion;
    private Integer CodigoMoneda;
    private String CodSubProducto;
    private String Plazo;
    private Integer FechaEmision;
    private Integer FechaVencimiento;
    private BigDecimal Monto;
    private BigDecimal MontoOrigen;
    private BigDecimal TasaBase;
    private BigDecimal TasaPeriodo;
    private BigDecimal MontoOrgIntPeriodo;
    private BigDecimal MontoFinalOrg;
    private String RUC;
    private String RUE;
    private String FiscaliaRegional;
    private String FiscaliaZonal;
}
```

I am working with rest template and the application requests a client certificate that loads correctly, the endpoints need a header with an access token which I obtain from another endpoint, which works correctly.

My main problem is that when trying to consume this endpoint, which are the resources, it shows me this error:

**Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`) at [Source: (org.springframework. util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]]**

By leaving my controller like this, it returns a response that there are invalid parameters and returns null

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/emision-pesos", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<EmisionPesosDto> emisionPesos(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String accessToken,
                                                        @RequestBody EmisionPesosBody emisionPesosBody){
       EmisionPesosDto response = emisionPesoService.postEmisionPesos(emisionPesosBody, accessToken);
       return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
```

{
"code": 400,
"message": "Parámetro inválido",
"payload": {
"fiscaliaRegional": null,
"ruc": null,
"rue": null,
"fiscaliaZonal": null,
"codigoMoneda": null,
"plazo": null,
"codSubProducto": null,
"fechaVencimiento": null,
"montoOrgIntPeriodo": null,
"tasaPeriodo": null,
"numOperacion": null,
"monto": null,
"montoFinalOrg": null,
"codProducto": null,
"fechaEmision": null,
"montoOrigen": null,
"tasaBase": null
}
}

Swagger Documentation:

```
Request
{
  "CodigoMoneda": 999,
  "Plazo": 7,
  "MontoDeposito": 105000,
  "IndicadorRenovacion": "S",
  "RutCliente": 61935400,
  "DigitoRutCliente": "1",
  "NumCuentaCorriente": 23909000386,
  "RUC": "000022010212467",
  "RUE": "000000012229907",
  "FiscaliaRegional": "005",
  "FiscaliaZonal": "000500",
  "RutUsuarioEmisor": 12878658,
  "DigitoRutUsuarioEmisor": "9"
}

Response

{
  "CodigoMoneda": 999,
  "Plazo": 7,
  "MontoDeposito": 105000,
  "IndicadorRenovacion": "S",
  "RutCliente": 61935400,
  "DigitoRutCliente": "1",
  "NumCuentaCorriente": 23909000386,
  "RUC": "000022010212467",
  "RUE": "000000012229907",
  "FiscaliaRegional": "005",
  "FiscaliaZonal": "000500",
  "RutUsuarioEmisor": 12878658,
  "DigitoRutUsuarioEmisor": "9"
}
```

That is what I have in the documentation that the client gave me

Answer (score 1):

The version `emisionPesos(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String accessToken, @RequestBody EmisionPesosBody emisionPesosBody)` is correct.

The other version with multiple arg annotated as `@RequestBody` is wrong - only one arg can be `@RequestBody`. The first arg is an integer so the deserialiser, which gets an object start, ie ”{“ and not an integer, complains.

You will have to check the api definition for desa-dapinstituciones.bancoestado.cl to sort out the missing parameters. Do you have a swagger doc for the POST to api-gtw-emision-pesos/dap-min-pub/emision-pesos.
?

Comment: Add the output and input that I have in the documentation provided by the client

Comment: Can you add System.out.println(emisionPesosBody) as the first line of emisionPesos and post what gets printed?

Comment: I did not understand you in the controller or service?

Comment: In the controller

Comment: does not show anything when trying to print the emisionPesosBody

Comment: This is probably the cause of your issue - an empty POST request body. Please use Postman to post the request to you service. The body should be as per your example Request but just the parts between the {} inclusive. If it fails add the Postman curl (find under "</>" on the right) to your question.

Comment: It keeps showing me the same thing:

"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]"

Comment: That's because you are using the wrong definition of emisionPesos in your Controller, ie  emisionPesos('@RequestHeader("Authorization") String accessToken,
                                        '@RequestBody Integer CodigoMoneda,
                                        '@RequestBody Integer Plazo, etc. You need to use emisionPesos('@RequestHeader("Authorization") String accessToken, '@RequestBody EmisionPesosBody emisionPesosBody) as per this answer.

Comment: This is how my controller looks like:` @PostMapping(value = "/emision-pesos", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public EmisionPesosDto emisionPesos(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String accessToken,
                                        @RequestBody EmisionPesosBody emisionPesosBody) {
        return emisionPesoService.postEmisionPesos(emisionPesosBody , accessToken);
    }`

but i get this momo response: `{ "code": 400, "message": "Parámetro inválido "payload": {"tasaBase": null,"montoFinalOrg": null,"..... }
}`

Comment: There must be a phantom controller running or a path problem. This message "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type java.lang.Integer from Object value (token JsonToken.START_OBJECT);" literally means that the '@RequestBody of method being called in the controller is set to an Integer, not  EmisionPesosBody